# Expresso Store: payment gateway settings in filesystem

Tags: expresso-store, config, payment-gateway, config-overrides, configuration-variables

Is it possible to store payment gateway settings in the file system, eg `config.php`?

For example, I might want to have different settings for different environments, eg test gateway API for staging server/site and live gateway API for production server/site

Thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible with Store - the way Omnipay is integrated with its abstracted settings methods it only looks in the database. A good feature request for Vector though! (Likewise for CartThrob.)